# Blocking port 21 causes outgoing FTP to fail

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ftp

I recently migrated our server away from using FTP to exclusively SFTP.  I would like to block port 21 in the firewall now that it is not needed for incoming FTP connections.  However, when I did this, any PHP script run on my server which connected to FTP servers ON OTHER SYSTEMS all failed.  It was my understanding that port 21 was only used for incoming FTP connections, but my experience says otherwise.

Do I have to leave 21 open if I want to use FTP connections to other servers?

iptables before modifications:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

iptables after modification:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: It sounds like you also blocked outgoing connections to port 21.

Comment: Post your iptables rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to leave 21 open if I want to use FTP connections to other
>   servers?

Yes, but no.

Yes, it has to be "open" to "outbound" or "egress" connections. No, it does not need to be open to inbound connections for FTP to work. There is a difference between ingress and egress rules so a port does not merely have to be "open" or "closed". It can be open to input, but not output and vice versa.

If you clamped down on all FTP, inbound ***and*** outbound, then that would be why your server cannot connect. Check your rules to make sure that traffic is allowed out but not in. In iptables, that would pertain to what table the rule applies to. For example, your input table would reject incoming requests, and your output table would allow `ESTABLISHED,RELATED`

(`iptables -L` would be helpful to see)

Comment: I was using system-config-securitylevel and not directly issuing iptables commands.  Here is what my iptables looked like before the change: http://pastebin.com/09nZ5iur and here it is after: http://pastebin.com/ZxnBZ4D8

Comment: @smusumeche In your output chain: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` (and make sure to save your iptables rules!)